# Oracle to T-SQL CTE conversion errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

Having trouble converting Oracle syntax to T-SQL. Trying to convert the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (WITH NEW_USERS AS (SELECT WPP.USER_ID
                         FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM WPP
                       MINUS
                       SELECT PP.USER_ID FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_PARTICIPANT_DIM PP)
     SELECT EWP.USER_ID
           ,EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG
       FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM EWP
      INNER JOIN NEW_USERS N
         ON (EWP.USER_ID = N.USER_ID)
      WHERE EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG = 1)
```

Conversion attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM (WITH NEW_USERS AS (SELECT WPP.USER_ID
                         FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM WPP
                       EXCEPT
                       SELECT PP.USER_ID FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_PARTICIPANT_DIM PP)
     SELECT EWP.USER_ID
           ,EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG
       FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM EWP
      INNER JOIN NEW_USERS N
         ON (EWP.USER_ID = N.USER_ID)
      WHERE EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG = 1)
```

SQL Server returned the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow for [CTE in subquery](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with):

```
WITH NEW_USERS AS (SELECT WPP.USER_ID
                   FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM WPP
                   EXCEPT    -- Oracle has MINUS
                   SELECT PP.USER_ID 
                   FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_PARTICIPANT_DIM PP)
SELECT EWP.USER_ID
       ,EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG
FROM DSS_ERS_STAGE.ES_W_PARTICIPANT_DIM EWP
INNER JOIN NEW_USERS N
   ON (EWP.USER_ID = N.USER_ID)
WHERE EWP.CANDIDATE_1_0_FLAG = 1;
```

Second thing: SQL Server has [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) keyword instead of `MINUS`.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer in a few minutes when I'm allowed.